# I want to serial number rows in Data From Phpexcel codeigniter

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to use the following code to serial number the Excel sheet rows generated using phpExcel in CodeIgniter.

```
$exceldata="";
foreach ($rs->result_array() as $key=>$row){
    $exceldata[] = array_merge([$key],$row);
}
```

This numbers the rows, but the problem is the first row number is blank. The number 1 starts from the second row.

Comment: show me the output of this array  and after print_r($rs->result_array());    \\ after print_r($exceldata);